# Update an item inside a document's array

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have a model that looks like this:

```
const List = new Schema({
    name: { type: String, unique: true, required: true, dropDups: true },
    cards: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Card' }],
    orderItems: [{ value: Number, card: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Card' } }]
});
```

And a document base of that model that looks like this:

```
{ _id: ObjectId: ("1234567890"), cards: [...], OrderItems: [{ card: ObjectId: ("0987654321"), value: 1.1, _id: ObjectId: ("1029384756") }] }
```

I want to update the value of the only object that's in the OrderItem's array of my document, I tried the most obvious methods like:

```
doc.OrderItems[0].value = 1.2;
doc.save();
```

but that's not working, how can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the method I was using was correct, the issue was when I was calling the parameters in my server function trough my endpoint